# Difference between np.int64(x) and x.astype(np.int64) in Numpy

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

If I have an array `x` that I want to convert to a specific `dtype`, the recommended method is `x.astype(dtype)`. However, it seems you can also use the `dtype` as a constructor directly via `dtype(x)`. Here is an example from an IPython session:

```py
In [1]: import numpy as np

In [2]: x = np.arange(12, dtype=float)

In [3]: x
Out[3]: array([ 0.,  1.,  2.,  3.,  4.,  5.,  6.,  7.,  8.,  9., 10., 11.])

In [4]: x.dtype
Out[4]: dtype('float64')

In [5]: np.int64(x)
Out[5]: array([ 0,  1,  2,  3,  4,  5,  6,  7,  8,  9, 10, 11], dtype=int64)

In [6]: x.astype(np.int64)
Out[6]: array([ 0,  1,  2,  3,  4,  5,  6,  7,  8,  9, 10, 11], dtype=int64)
```

---

What is the difference between these two methods? The `astype` method allows you to control things like copying, casting rules, and whether subclasses are okay. What does the other method actually do? Is it an alias for a specific setting?

Comment: Not sure why this was closed. The other question is specifically not about the same thing. A dtype argument in specific functions is NOT the same as asking about a class constructor.

Comment: Not only that, but the `astype` method has changed since the other question was posted and answered.

Comment: I'm not sure the `duplicate` answers your question, since it really addresses what you do in line [2], specifying the dtype as part of the array creation step.  I don't see anything wrong with [5], but it does look odd - I've rarely used it.

Comment: @hpaulj "I'm not sure the duplicate answers your question" - then I hope you vote to reopen this question. It's really annoying to deal with trigger-happy StackOverflow question closers.

Comment: I've remopened it.  That said, what I wrote about `astype` earlier is relevant.  Since both `astype` and `np.int64` are compiled, we can't (readily) compare the underlying actions.  My guess is that at some level in the `c` code they end up doing the same thing.

Comment: A minor different I found with testing.  If the array is already `np.int64` dtype, `np.int64(x)` returns `x`, same `id` and same databuffer.  `astype` will return a copy, or maybe a `view` if given the right parameter.